# Why redmine plugin installation failded? (with bitnami redmine installer)

Tags: redmine, agile, bitnami

I'm trying to install [redmine agile plugin](http://www.redminecrm.com/projects/agile/pages/1) into my environment.

But I couldn't complete the task with the error below...
How can I solve this error?

I made my environment using bitnami [redmine installer](https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine/installer), the redmine version is Redmine 3.1.0-0 and OS is Cent OS 7.

```
Installing mysql2 0.3.14 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib

Gem files will remain installed in /opt/redmine-3.1.0-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/mysql2-0.3.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/redmine-3.1.0-0/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.14'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Did you check `mkmf.log`?

Comment: Yes, contents of the log file is almost the same as error message above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [document](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Redmine#How_to_install_a_plugin_on_Redmine.3f) said, When you install plugin into redmine with bitnami, you have to execute `use_redmine` command after move to redmine installed directry such as `/opt/redmine-3.1.0-0`.

Here is the example command when you install redmine plugin.

```
$ cd installdir
$ ./use_redmine
$ cd apps/redmine/htdocs
$ bundle install --without development test
$ bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_agile RAILS_ENV=production
```

You need to be noted that this command have to be executed only when you use bitnami image.
After you execute this command, additional table will be created into redmine database, without it, plugin won't work properly.